# Find Same Array value from one single array and merge its value into new array group wise

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have one multidimensional array and from that array I want to create a new array from same id1 from first array and want to get all matching sub arrays value into its inner array with its element

Below is the array I have:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id1] => 109891
            [id2] => 67
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id1] => 828393
            [id2] => 67
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id1] => 828393
            [id2] => 68
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id1] => 816714
            [id2] => 70
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id1] => 816714
            [id2] => 67
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id1] => 816714
            [id2] => 68
        )
)
```

And I want output like in this way:

```
Array
(
    [109891] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [id2] => 67
            )
        )
     [828393] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [id2] => 67
            )
            [1] => Array
            (
                [id2] => 68
            )
        )  
     [816714] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [id2] => 70
            )
            [1] => Array
            (
                [id2] => 67
            )
            [2] => Array
            (
                [id2] => 68
            )
        )     

)
```

Any Help Would be Appreciated

Comment: Can you show us something you actually tried to accomplish such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$output = array();
foreach($input as $r) {
    $id1 = $r['id1'];
    if(!isset($output[$id1])) {
        $output[$id1] = array();
    }
    $output[$id1][] = array('id2' => $r['id2']);
}
print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 2):

origin array:

```
$array = array(
        array('id1' => '109891', 'id2' => '67'),
        array('id1' => '828393', 'id2' => '67'),
        array('id1' => '828393', 'id2' => '68'),
        array('id1' => '816714', 'id2' => '70'),

    );
```

use this foreach:

```
$new = array();
foreach($array as $element) {
    $new[$element['id1']][] = array('id2' => $element['id2']);
}
```

or this in a function:

```
function editMyArray($array) {
    $newArray = array();
    foreach($array as $element) {
        $newArray[$element['id1']][] = array('id2' => $element['id2']);
    }
    return $newArray;
}
```

Output:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new);
echo "</pre>";

Array
(
    [109891] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id2] => 67
                )

        )

    [828393] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id2] => 67
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id2] => 68
                )

        )

    [816714] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id2] => 70
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below tested code:

```
$i = 0;
$sepr = 0;
$arr = array();
foreach($your_array as $your_reslut_array) {
$k = $i; $k = ($k > 0 ? $k-1 : 0);
foreach($your_reslut_array as $key => $value) {
    if($key != "ID" && $value != $your_reslut_array[$k][$key]) {
        $sepr++;
    }
}
$arr[$sepr][] = $car;
$i++;
}

print_r($arr);
```